# How can I get template html text

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I know that knockout has method ko.renderTemplate() https://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/knockout-js-pro-tips-working-with-templates/

So I have next code:

```
var templateHtmlText = ko.renderTemplate('packageView', package[0])
```

but it returns `"<!--[ko_memo:5c90e0726c7e506b]-->"`

How can I get ready html code in variable with applied bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply an element for knockout to bind to (`elem` in this example). RenderTemplate then binds the data (`obs` in this example) to this element. If you want to store the result in a variable, then grab the elements `innerHTML`:

```js
var obs = ko.observable({demo:'demo text'});
var elem = document.createElement('div');

ko.renderTemplate('template', obs, null, elem);
console.log(elem.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/html" id="template">
  <span data-bind="text: demo"></span>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! But what if I use $parent, $root in template?

Comment: You can supply the entire [binding context](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) in the second parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you, I tried tour solution and its works, but I have next error Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return $parent.DisplayPricePerPerson }"
Message: $parent is not defined

Comment: ko.renderTemplate('packageview', qwe.Packages[0], null, el)

Comment: qwe.Packages[0] is probably just some data, not an entire binding context (containing references to $parent and $root etc.). That is why the errror occurs. Alternatively you could just render the entire html to all the data and grab the `innerHTML` of the element you are looking for.